# Is it possible to remove duplicates from a string in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

So been working with some data and currently have output along the lines of

Customer  | Reasons
Customer1 | Answer1, Answer3, Answer2, Answer4, Answer5, Answer1, Answer3, Answer1

Is there anyway in Big Query standard sql to rid myself of duplicates within this string and end with the output below?

Customer  | Reasons
Customer1 | Answer1, Answer3, Answer2, Answer4, Answer5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I understood the question correctly, you want something like:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT s, ', ')
   FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(Customer1, ', ')) AS s) AS Customer1
FROM dataset.table
```

This splits the string on the `', '` separator, then aggregates the substrings into a new string with duplicates removed using the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

While voting up Elliott's answer - wanted to add another option (BigQuery Standard SQL):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Customer1' customer, 'Answer1, Answer3, Answer2, Answer4, Answer5, Answer1, Answer3, Answer1' answers 
)
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT answer
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(answers, ', ')) AS answer 
  ), ', ') AS answers)   
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

which produces result you need

```sql
Row customer    answers  
1   Customer1   Answer1, Answer3, Answer2, Answer4, Answer5
```

In case if for some reason you would wanted to have those values ordered - you just add one line as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Customer1' customer, 'Answer1, Answer3, Answer2, Answer4, Answer5, Answer1, Answer3, Answer1' answers 
)
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT answer
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(answers, ', ')) AS answer 
    ORDER BY answer
  ), ', ') AS answers)   
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```sql
Row customer    answers  
1   Customer1   Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, Answer5
```

Note: most likely need in ordering is not relevant for particular use case in your question - it can be handy in other cases